# How to replace TAB char in a CLOB column?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, regexp-replace

I've been searching a lot for a solution but found none.

My simple question: I have a Oracle12.2 table with a CLOB column, here and there are TABS, how to remove them in my sqlplus queries?

Below instructions work well

```
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 3, 130) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 9, 133) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161),
```

But when I try to remove the tabs with i.e.

```
regexp_replace('dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161)', chr(9), ' ',),
```

I get errors.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is my query:

```
select
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 9, 91) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 4, 60) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 24, 100) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 3, 130) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 9, 133) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161) ||';'||                 
L79T1.trno ||';'|| L79T1.datereg ||';'|| L79T1.trtype ||';'|| L79T1.trstat
from L79T1  
inner join L80T2 on (L80T2.trno = L79T1.trno)
where L79T1.trtype = '518' AND
    L79T1.datereg >= trunc(sysdate) -13 AND
    L79T1.datereg < trunc(sysdate);
```

And here is the ouput:

```
P0042842 ;2000;011112G016V3AN0033      ;P02;000065186;25674XX             ;295428109;2020-12-11 15:05:07;518;30
P0042883 ;2000;013494G010QVAN0033      ;P02;000037752;26545XX             ;295428110;2020-12-11 15:05:08;518;30
P0042485 ;2000;011112G016V3AN0033      ;P02;000050610;25668XX             ;295428112;2020-12-11 15:05:09;518;30
```

Tabs have been lost in the copy/paste, sorry.

Could it be on the sqlplus output formatting parameters I use ?

```
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET ECHO OFF
SET FEED OFF
SET VERIFY OFF
SET HEADING OFF
SET NEWPAGE NONE
SET LINESIZE 300
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET BUFFER 10000
```

Comment: What errors do you get? Is it a typo that you have quotes around `'dbms_lob.substr...'`? Because that is wrong. Also you have a trailing comma at the end: `' ',)`

Comment: Well, it is not a typo, it i just one of nth my tries... when you don't know what else to do. The comma at the end is because it is part of a larger sql and, as I said, it works all well so I thought to give you just that part... sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: No worries! If you remove the quotes and that comma (INSIDE the parentheses, not the one outside), let us know what errors you get.

Comment: I did. Run [   replace(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161), chr(9))   ] and got no errors but the tabs are still there

Comment: Ok. Try `ascii(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 1, 169))` and see what number it says. If it's a tab character it'll say 9. If it's a space it'll be 32.

Comment: or you can use `SELECT dump( dbms_lob.substr(tridata, 4000, 1) ) FROM L80T2` whether contains the value 9 among comma-seperated integer values.

Comment: @kfinity I tried your suggestion with more details, I always get 32 i.e. `....;000008712;26923XX1A           ;49;65;32;32;32;32` but when I redirect the output to file the tabs appear `sql < stats.sql >outfile`

Comment: @kfinity  see what I get please [Notepad++](https://ibb.co/KjRqjCJ)

Comment: @Barbaros Özhan I don't know what to to with the output, it is here [dumpL80T2](https://ibb.co/p4zKgCH)

Comment: search within this output whether to see `, 9 ,` or not ...

Comment: @emare Basically there aren't any 9's in the output, but there are a lot of 32s - so the "tabs" are actually spaces in the clob data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Barbaros' answer, it sounds like you want to remove whitespace (EITHER tabs OR trailing spaces) from your fields. In that case, I'd suggest adding RTRIM, to only remove trailing spaces from the right side:

```
select
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 9, 91) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 4, 60) ||';'||
RTRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 24, 100), CHR(9))) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 3, 130) ||';'||
dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 9, 133) ||';'||
RTRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161), CHR(9))) ||';'||        
...
```

If you know you only have spaces and no tabs, you can just use RTRIM alone.

Regexp_replace is a bit slower, but you can do something similar with it - to remove trailing whitespace:

```
regexp_replace(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 24, 100),'[[:space:]]+$') ||';'||
```

Comment: `RTRIM(REPLACE(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161), CHR(9)))` worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just a `REPLACE()` function with two arguments might solve the problem such as

```
SELECT REPLACE(tridata, CHR(9))
  FROM tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0accc881dac14a3e91df49bbfc56f09d)</kbd>

*P.S: Wrapping up a function within quotes is a typo*

Comment: Thanks. I tried with    replace(dbms_lob.substr(L80T2.tridata, 20, 161), chr(9))     but the tabs are still there, not removed.

Comment: you're welcome @emare . Can you share what you have met within a demo please ?

Comment: The deom seems to work, I don't know how to share it TRIDATA  NEW_TRIDATA
26661XX              25668XX               27756XX             
END  26661XX             25668XX             27756XX             
END